# jQuery Selecting DOM Element by data-attribute with multiple Identifiers in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Note: this isn't a basic question on Querying by data-attributes**

The problem I'm having is that I have certain elements like so:

```
<div data-step="1, 4">
```

I have figured out how to step through each `[data-step]` and extract  the `1, 4` and create events for them, etc.

**Let's say I'm trying to Query and grab this exact data-step but all I'm given is: 4**

```
$('[data-step="4"]') 
// this won't work of course

$('[data-step="1, 4"]')
// obviously this will work, but at this point I'm only given the index
// which will only be ONE of these numbers
```

Basically given (for examples sake, 4) How can I easily Query the selector to go out and grab `[data-step="1, 4"]`?

All I'm able to come up with is a loop, that goes through each data-step, strips out everything and sees if there is a match. Is there an easier way potentially?

Comment: If you can change your data-step attribute to be delimited by spaces, you can use $("[data-step~='4']").

Comment: @ajshort Seems like the simplest solution here! Luckily I'm able to change that, much easier to handle this way. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~=` will find element with an attribute which has a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces. Works in your case also.

```
$('[data-step~="4"]')
```

`*=` will find element with an attribute which has a value containing the given substring.

```
$('[data-step*="4"]')
```

Comment: wow how did I not know about `~=` !! The attributes contains word selector, very nice. This works perfectly! And to my suprise does not pick up things like `[data-step=14]` if I'm only doing `~=4`. Thanks so much!

Comment: It is important to know that the provided selectors do not work for attributes like `data-step="1, 4, 5"` and `data-step="1, 44"` respectively.

Comment: @VisioN: `*=` will work for `data-step="1, 4, 5"` and finding `44` is not what OP is looking for if understand it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `filter` solution:

```
var search = 4;
$("[data-step]").filter(function() {
    return $.inArray("" + search, $(this).data("step").split(/,\s*/)) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: Very nice! For some reason I was getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'split'` until I changed it to `.attr('data-step')`. But this works perfectly as well!

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS It seems that you use the old version of jQuery =)

Comment: `1.7.2` still yeah :/ Upgrading soon hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use * before = it will return all data-step wich is contain substring 'value'
    $('[data-step*="value"]')